# Como transformar horas em segundos no R?

Tags: r

Eu tenho os seguintes horários:

> 2:00:00 3:00:00 6:00:00 4:00:00 4:00:00 3:00:48 1:00:00 3:00:00 2:00:00 4:00:00 1:30:00
>    2:00:00 1:00:00 3:00:00 4:00:00 4:30:00 5:00:00 1:00:00 1:30:00 2:00:00 3:00:00 3:00:48 
>    4:00:00 4:30:00

**Como transformar tudo isso em segundos?**
Ja tentei de varias formas e nao consigo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 hora é igual a 3600 segundos... então...

```
# Vamos ler os dados
x <- unlist(strsplit("2:00:00 3:00:00 6:00:00 4:00:00 4:00:00 3:00:48 1:00:00 3:00:00 2:00:00 4:00:00 1:30:00 2:00:00 1:00:00 3:00:00 4:00:00 4:30:00 5:00:00 1:00:00 1:30:00 2:00:00 3:00:00 3:00:48 4:00:00 4:30:00", "[[:space:]]+"))
x
# [1] "2:00:00" "3:00:00" "6:00:00" "4:00:00" "4:00:00" "3:00:48" "1:00:00"
# [8] "3:00:00" "2:00:00" "4:00:00" "1:30:00" "2:00:00" "1:00:00" "3:00:00"
#[15] "4:00:00" "4:30:00" "5:00:00" "1:00:00" "1:30:00" "2:00:00" "3:00:00"
#[22] "3:00:48" "4:00:00" "4:30:00"
```

Vamos usar o Split. Multiplicar o primeiro numero por 3600 e o segundo por 60 e o ultimo por 1. E adicionar eles entre si, podemos utilizar uma 'matrix multiplication' para isso.

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), function(n) as.numeric(n) %*% c(3600, 60, 1))
```

Outra alternativa utilizando o POSIXct (subtraindo meianoite[segundos]):

```
as.numeric(strptime(x, format="%H:%M:%S") - as.POSIXct(format(Sys.Date())), units="secs")
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado !!!! Voce sabe como posso colocar isso numa nova variavel e add no meu banco de dados ?